# Issue decrementing in a do while loop

Tags: c++, loops, methods, do-while, decrement

I'm having an issue decrementing using a do while loop. Everything is broken up into separate files to keep the class & methods/functions separate (as well as keeping the main clear).

The issue I'm having is that it decrements once, but when it loops back through it goes right back to the same value and decrements to the same result. I know it's probably something stupid I did, but I haven't noticed it yet!

**To be specific the error I'm getting is when I call the useBrake method.**

Gondola.h

```
#ifndef _GONDOLA_CLASS
#define _GONDOLA_CLASS

class Gondola
{

private:
    double load; // load <= 500
    double speed; // Speed <= 20
    double condition; // 0-100

public:

    //Constructors
    Gondola();
    Gondola(double ld, double spd, double cnd);

    //Accessor methods (getters)
    double getLoad() const;
    double getSpeed() const;
    double getCondition() const;

    //Mutator Methods methods (setters)
    bool setLoad(double ld);
    bool setSpeed(double spd);
    bool setCondition(double cnd);

    //Other Methods
    double useBrake(int slowSpeed);

};

#endif
```

Gondola.cpp

```
//Accessor and mutator methods
#include <iostream>
#include "Gondola.h"

using namespace std;

//Constructors

Gondola::Gondola()
{
    load = 0;
    speed = 0;
    condition = 100;
}

Gondola::Gondola(double ld, double spd, double condit)
{
    if(!setLoad(ld))
    {
        load = 500;
    }

    if(!setSpeed(spd))
    {
        speed = 20;
    }

    if(!setCondition(condit))
    {
        condition = 100;
    }

}

//Accessor Methods

double Gondola::getLoad() const
{
    return load;
}

double Gondola::getSpeed() const
{
    return speed;
}

double Gondola::getCondition() const
{
    return condition;
}

//Mutator Methods

bool Gondola::setLoad(double ld)
{
    bool validLoad = (ld > 0) && (ld <= 500);
    if(validLoad)
    {
        load = ld;
    }

    return validLoad;
}

bool Gondola::setSpeed(double spd)
{
    bool validSpeed = (spd > 0) && (spd <= 20);
    if(validSpeed)
    {
        speed = spd;
    }

    return validSpeed;
}


bool Gondola::setCondition(double cnd)
{
    bool validCondition = (cnd > 0) && (cnd <= 100);
    if(validCondition)
    {
        condition = cnd;
    }

    return validCondition;
}

//Other Functions

double Gondola::useBrake(int slowSpeed)
{
    char userResponse = ' ';
    bool validInput = false;
    int newSpeed = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Do you want to use the brake?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter y for 'yes' or n for 'no'" << endl;
        cin >> userResponse;
        validInput = (userResponse == 'y') || (userResponse == 'n');

        if(!validInput)
        {
            cout << "Invalid response. Please try again!" << endl;
        }

        if(userResponse == 'y')
        {
            newSpeed = (slowSpeed - 5);
            speed = newSpeed;
        }
    }while(!validInput);

    return slowSpeed;
}

bool continueBraking()                                                   // Asks the user if they want to continue. If yes, the braking loop continues. If no, the program continues
{

    char userResponse = ' ';
    bool validInput = false;

    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you wish to continue braking?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter y for 'yes' or n for 'no'" << endl;
        cin >> userResponse;
        validInput = (userResponse == 'y') || (userResponse == 'n');
        if (!validInput)
        {
            cout << "Invalid response. Please try again!" << endl;
        }
    } while (!validInput);
    return(userResponse == 'y');
}

bool askToContinue()                                                         // Asks the user if they want to continue. If yes, the loop restarts. If no, the program exits.
{

    char userResponse = ' ';
    bool validInput = false;

    do
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you wish to continue?" << endl;
        cout << "Enter y for 'yes' or n for 'no'" << endl;
        cin >> userResponse;
        validInput = (userResponse == 'y') || (userResponse == 'n');
        if (!validInput)
        {
            cout << "Invalid response. Please try again!" << endl;
        }
    } while (!validInput);
    return(userResponse == 'y');
}
```

Main.cpp

```
/*

    Paul Christopher
    Skill 2.2
    Description: Program creates gondola object and then the user
                 enters in the load, speed, and condition. The program
                 also has methods to dump and use the brake to slow 
                 the speed of the gondola by 5 kph.

*/

//main program code

#include <iostream>
#include "Gondola.h"

using namespace std;


bool continueBraking();
bool askToContinue();


int main()
{

    //Variables
    double gondolaLoad = 0.0;
    double gondolaSpeed = 0.0;
    double gondolaCondition = 0.0;

    do
    {
        //Object Declaration
        Gondola gondola;

        //Change variables
        cout << "Enter a load size for this gondola (1-500): " << endl;
        cin >> gondolaLoad;
        gondola.setLoad(gondolaLoad);

        cout << "Enter a speed for this gondola (<=20): " << endl;
        cin >> gondolaSpeed;
        gondola.setSpeed(gondolaSpeed);

        cout << "Enter a condition for this gondola (1-100): " << endl;
        cin >> gondolaCondition;
        gondola.setCondition(gondolaCondition);

        //New Output
        cout << "Gondola's new load, speed, and condition: " << endl; 
        cout << gondola.getLoad() << endl;
        cout << gondola.getSpeed() << endl;
        cout << gondola.getCondition() << endl;

        do
        {
            gondola.useBrake(gondolaSpeed);
            cout << "Gondola's new speed: " << gondola.getSpeed() << endl;

        }while(continueBraking());

        cout << "Gondola's new speed: " << gondola.getSpeed() << endl;

    }while(askToContinue());

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I see three `do-while` loops. Which is the one you're having a problem with?

Comment: Are you talking about `newSpeed = (slowSpeed - 5);`? That sets it to the same value each time through the loop, since `slowSpeed` never changes.

Comment: what result do you have, and what result do you expect ? give one set of values you entered in load speed and condition.

Comment: Common wrong usage of streams: No test for successful extraction before testing the extracted value (it might be unchanged)

Comment: @Barmar Yes I am talking about that part. The max speed you can enter is 20 so when it decrements it'll subtract 5 (the amount of braking) to get 15. Not sure if I have to get it to loop for the assignment, but it's something I wanted to add to 'go the extra mile' (plus it helps with my understanding of how things work).

Comment: @philippelhardy I'm trying to make the speed value go down by 5 each time a user wants to break within that loop. Problem is, it's only going to 15 and then only going to 15. I removed the const from the bool methods, so it's not that

Answer (score 0):

you wrote these

```
double getLoad() const;
double getSpeed() const;
double getCondition() const;
```

so when you call these in do-while loop , the return values will not change once you have get through before.

Comment: actually that still didn't work by removing the const. Still only goes to 15 then stops. I think the error is in my loop to utilize the braking method. I'm going to play around with that

Answer (score 0):

you wrote

```
return slowSpeed;
```

in Gondola.cpp

```
double Gondola::useBrake(int slowSpeed)
```

You should return speed instead,I think.